# Ionic capacitor not dismissing cookies on App Close

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

My ionic app has a component where a user can select a location which would be saved to a session cookie to be used later on in the app. This is intended to be a session cookie and thus be deleted on closure of the app. On Web browser, The cookie is succesfully reset on browser close, however it persists on Android. Im using the angular ngx-cookie-service.
My chose Location Component:

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { Geolocation } from "@capacitor/geolocation";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";
declare var google:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chose-location',
  templateUrl: './chose-location.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chose-location.page.scss'],
})
export class ChoseLocationPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public $modal: ModalController,
    public $router: Router,
    private $cookie: CookieService
  ) { }
public selLat;selLong;
   initMap(lat,long) {
    try{

     const myLatLng = { lat: lat, lng : long };
     const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
       zoom: 25,
       center: myLatLng,
     });
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: myLatLng,
       map,
       title: "Branch Location",
       draggable:true
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', (event)=> {
         let selLat = marker.position.lat()
        let selLong = marker.position.lng()
        this.$cookie.set("selLat",selLat);
        this.$cookie.set("selLong",selLong);
     });
 }
 catch{}
 } 
 changeLocation(){

   this.$modal.dismiss({
     dismissed:true
   })
 }
  async ngOnInit() {

    const coordinates = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    let lat = coordinates.coords.latitude
    let long = coordinates.coords.longitude;
    this.initMap(lat,long);
  }
  close(){
    this.$modal.dismiss({
      dismissed:true
    })
  }
}
```

How can i ensure the cookie gets deleted on app close for mobile platforms ??

Comment: I don't have any idea for how to resolve it. But, you can maybe try to delete the cookie when the app loads.

Comment: OMG, thats genius, Ill try to delete the cookies on app load. Thanks